# What is the contrapositive of this theorem?

Tags: graph-theory

This theorem: A connected graph has a Euler path but no Euler cycle if and only if exactly two vertices have odd degree.

Is it: If at least one vertex is of even degree, then the graph has no Euler path OR the graph has a Euler cycle? Can someone explain? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

$p:\quad $ A connected graph has a Euler path but no Euler cycle.
$\lnot p:\;$ A connected graph has no Euler path or has a Euler cycle.

$q:\quad$ A connected graph has exactly two vertices of odd degree.
$\lnot q:\;$ A connected graph does not have exactly two vertices of odd degree.

You have a *biconditional* statement: key words are *if and only if*, so the main connective of the theorem is $\iff: \quad p \iff q$.  That is, the theorem is not a single implication, which is the type of statement to which the contrapositive makes sense.

The contrapositive of an *implication* $p\to q$ is, of course, $\lnot q \to \lnot p$.

But note that in biconditional, we have that $p \iff q \equiv \lnot p \iff \lnot q$. You can confirm this via a truth table. In any case, we rarely speak of a contrapositive of a biconditional. If you are going to try to write the equivalent form $\lnot p \iff \lnot q$, you need more than a single-directional implication.

The "contrapositive" of your *biconditional* needs to be a biconditional as well:

> "A connected graph does not have exactly two vertices of odd degree if and only if  it has either no Euler path, or it has an Euler cycle".

Answer (score 0):

The contrapositive is "A graph does not have exactly two vertices of odd degree (it may have fewer or more), if and only if either it has no Euler path, or it has an Euler cycle".

This could, for example, provide a way to prove that a graph has an Euler cycle : prove that it does not have exactly two vertices of odd degree, and that it has an Euler path.

*EDIT:* In general, however, we speak of the contrapositive when the implication goes in only one direction. The "contrapositive" of an equivalence sounds a little weird, although you could say that you are just taking the contrapositives of the two implications and putting them together...

Comment: The theorem is a biconditional: an if and only if statement. So if you are going to speak of its contrapositive, it needs to be a biconditional, as well.

Comment: Yes, I have added an edit. In general "contrapositive" refers only to implications, not equivalences...

Comment: I am referencing the OP's theorem: A connected graph has a Euler path but no Euler cycle **if and only if** exactly two vertices have odd degree. **That** is the theorem for which s/he wants the contrapositive. Why replicate an answer that's already been posted, virtually 10 minutes prior to your (originally incorrect) post?

Comment: Yes, I was confused on the meaning of "biconditional", sorry.